# Notice: Array to string conversion

Tags: php

```
if (isset($_POST['emaildistribution'])) 
{
    echo implode(',', $_POST['emaildistribution']);     
}

$first_name = $_POST['Fname']; 
$last_name = $_POST['Lname'];
$city = $_POST['city']; 
$department = $_POST['department']; 
$day = $_POST['day']; 
$tick = $_POST['tick']; 
$staffName = $_POST['staffName']; 
$permissions = $_POST['permGranted']; 
$PersonalComp = $_POST['PersonalComp']; 
$deskPhone = $_POST['deskPhone']; 
$mobPhone = $_POST['mobPhone']; 
$field = $_POST['field']; 
$submit = $_POST['confirm'];

$headers = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;"      cellpadding="10">';
$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>First Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['Fname']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Last Name:</strong> </td><td>" .  strip_tags($_POST['Lname']) . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Location:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['city']) . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Department:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['department']) . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Date:</strong> </td><td>" . $_POST['day'] . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Permissions as Other User:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['tick']) . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Other User:</strong> </td><td>" . $_POST['staffName'] . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Permissions:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['permGranted']) . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Hardware:</strong> </td><td>" . $_POST['PersonalComp'] . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>New Equipment:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['deskPhone']) . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Desk Phone:</strong> </td><td>" . $_POST['mobPhone'] . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Mobile Phone :</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['field']) . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email Distribtuion Groups :</strong> </td><td>" . ($_POST['emaildistribution']) . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";

if(isset($submit)) {

    // EDIT THE LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED WHENEVER EMAIL CHANGES
    mail($email_to,$email_subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";
}


?>
```

If i use serialize the code executes perfectly, but i dont want all the extra information it sends because it doesnt look tidy. Is there a simple way that i can convert emaildistribution which is an array into a string so it is passed by POST? I am new to PHP.

Answer (score 2):

[`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) is your friend here. Instead of just `echo`ing the value, use it:

```
if (isset($_POST['emaildistribution'])) 
{
    $_POST['emaildistribution']) = implode(',', $_POST['emaildistribution']);     
}
```